# Keytool - Import a certificate to the keystore

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am trying to import a certificate into a keystore.

Therefore i execute the following steps:

1. Create an empty keystore.jks file
2. Create the file contentent with the keytool: 
   `keytool -genkey -alias server-alias -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore keystore.jks`
3. Add my certificate to that keystore:
   `keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server-alias -file C:\server.cert -keystore keystore.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit`

But I always get the error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In step two you always generate a new key, but if you want to import a certificate and it's private key into the keystore you have to use the key that matches the certificate.

Hence you need the key you created before someone signed your server certificate (the one stored in C:\server.cert).

The following steps have to be performed in the right order:

1. Create a **random** public/private key pair. The private key is usually saved password protected
2. Create a certificate request containing the public key from step 1
3. Send the certificate request to a trust center which signs it and sends you back the certificate (the server.cert you have)
4. Save the private key from step 1 together with the returned certificate

Therefore you are always trying to re-do step 1 and 4 without step 2 and 3. Thus you are getting that "don't match" error.

Just complete all steps 1-4 after another. Or use the saved private key that belongs to the server.cert certificate (hopefully you still have it).

Comment: Can you clarify step 4? When I generate a new key with `keytool -genkey` is it not already saved in the keystore? So I just need to import the certificate? Or do I **have** to export that private key someone from keystore, bundle it with certificate, and then reimport them together back to keystore?